# Itune Application sharing blocking

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

IOS paid application sharing we need to block.

Planning to submit paid application in Apple store. Suppose a user brought application and download to Itunes account, then i sync to my mobile device, able to use that.

1.From itunes can we share application ipa to any other user?

2.is there any way to identify which apple id used for downloading?

3.any option for blocking user without downloading from apple store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps bought/downloaded from the app store are linked to the account that download the app. You can there for not just share the `IPA`.

On a jailbroke device you might be able to remove the security measures that restrict this. But what you are proposing is not possible with official App Store apps.

Comment: Apps Download to itunes accounts and  select that app and right click and click on showinfinder.. it will give an ipa file of selected application....can i share this ipa to any other user?

Comment: No, it is signed with your Apple Appstore account and will not run on a device that is not synced with your account.

Comment: ok, application only work in app id used for download? what about jailbroke device?

Comment: With a jailbroke device any could be possible.

Comment: we need identify jaibroken device and block using the app?  what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I have no idea, but use Google.

Comment: is there any way to identify apple id which is used for downloading application from apple store?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Ot would be a breach of privacy.

Comment: jailbreak device can also able to buy application from itunes store, how can i identify app is download through itunes/ cracked version ?

Comment: I have no idea, you should do some research on this. Start search google and stackoverflow. These kind of question have been asked many times.

Answer (score 1):

You cant code to UDID anymore since the update to the iTunes ToS. They are all account bound. In the cases I have tried to share the .ipa file the app data inside that app specific to me did not migrate to the new user